# HTML / CSS Random Line Below Image Object

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Hello I've been struggling with this for a bit now. When I import this image that is 215px by 215px it has extra space below it when I have the container to be 215px by 215px as well. I colored the background purple so the space can be seen. I also have another image which is literally the same setup (they share the same class) but that one doesn't have the line below and it takes up the entire container.

[image]

Below is the css and html code. Any help is appreciated!!

```css
/* controls the project card div*/
.project {
    /* background-color: chartreuse; */

    min-width: 14vw;
    max-width: 14vw;

    min-height: 35vh;
    max-height: 35vh;

    text-align: center;

    transition: 0.3s;
    transform: scale(1);
    /* overflow: hidden; */

}

/* controls the image of the cards */
.pp-container .main img {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    display: block;
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;

    object-position: center;

    object-fit: cover;

    border-radius: 15%;

    transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0;
    transform: box-shadow;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp-container" id="personal-projects">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>PERSONAL PROJECTS</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <a href="arduino_timer.html">
      <div class="project">
        <img src="./images/Arduino-Timer.svg">
        <h3>Arduino Timer</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="project">
        <img src="./images/Work-in-progress.svg">
        <h3>IMU Orientation</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe that it is possible for this line to have come from html, javascript or css

Comment: Is the aspect ratio of both the images the same? Have you tried object-fit: fill; instead?

Comment: I am going to take a wild guess and assume that since they are svgs that the clock was exported using the whiteboard which is causing the extra space.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula you are right they are SVGs. I exported them the same way I believe but I will double check. Thank you! This might be it